# Java: list files returns null on external storage on MacOS

Tags: java, macos

When I try to list the content of a folder on an external storage with `file.list()`, the method always returns `null`. The doc does not really help. It says:

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

In my case, the abstract pathname does denote a directory (according to Java itself) and the permissions seems fine.

Any help would be appreciated. So far, I found solution only for Android. I am using macOS Big Sur 11.4 (I don't have a linux or a windows machine to test) with JDK 15.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        var path = "/Volumes/MyStorage";
        var file = new File(path);

        System.out.println("Username: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
        System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());
        System.out.println("File is a directory: " + file.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("List of files: " + Arrays.toString(file.list()));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Username: username
File exists: true
File is a directory: true
List of files: null
```

The permissions seems fine:

```sh
$ ls -la /Volumes/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 root      wheel  128 May 29 21:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root      wheel  640 Jan  1  2020 ..
drwxrwxr-x  13 username  staff  510 May 29 20:52 MyStorage
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel    1 May 26 10:15 Macintosh HD -> /
```

As `username`, I have access to the entire structure of MyStorage. I can list the content of the disk using `ls /Volumes/MyStorage`.

### Edit:

As requested in comment, here is the stack trace of the error I get using `Files.list(Path.of(path))`:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Volumes/MyStorage: Operation not permitted
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:411)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:476)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3765)
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Which is very puzzling considering the permissions on the folder look fine. Also, other languages have no problem listing the folder (C, Python, and probably others). I tried running the working python script as a subprocess in Java, but it does not work (folder appears empty).

### Edit 2:

I have been running the java app within NetBeans so far. But if I run the java app via the shell (`java -jar myapp.jar`), then it works:

```sh
$ java -jar TestApplication.jar
Username: username
File exists: true
File is a directory: true
List of files: [.DocumentRevisions-V100, .DS_Store, .fseventsd, .Spotlight-V100, .TemporaryItems, .Trashes, private, work]
```

Is it possible for NetBeans (and only netbeans?) to not have the permission to list a folder?

### Edit 3:

Narrowing down the problem thanks to dan1st. When I pack the app with `packr` and run the `.app` file, then macOS asks me to give my authorization to list removable storage (the black rectangle hides the name of my app):
[image: macOS asking for permission to list removable storage contente]

If I click "Ok", then it works as expected. Unfortunately, We cannot add these authorization for NetBeans manually. Perhaps this is a problem for "Ask Different"?

Comment: What happens when using `Files.list(Path.of(path))`? Does this result in an exception? In that case, can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks, I get an error indeed. Looks like a permission issue, but it makes this problem even harder to understand...

Comment: What user does the application run under? Can you run `ls -la /Volumes/MyStorage`? What file system does the external storage use? What happens if you run the application as administrator/using `sudo`? Does it work with subdirectories? Can you access files?

Comment: Thank you for asking all these questions. It looks like it's working if I run the app outside of NetBeans (never thought it could be an issue). However, I don't understand why, within Netbeans (and within Netbeans only), the listing is not possible.

Comment: What happens with `ls -la` in NetBeans?

Comment: You mean with a subprocess? If yes, then I get nothing. The `ls -la` command ran within NetBeans yields nothing to stdout. Standard error shows `ls: MyStorage: Operation not Permitted`. It looks like a permission issue with the kind-of recent security system of macOS. See Edit #3

Comment: It might be related to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124185.

Comment: Running NetBeans via the Terminal seems to work for me (suggestions found via a link in a link in the link you have provided). I made an app using "Automator" that runs Netbeans via a shell script. This is not optimal, but at least it works for now. Until the dev team of Netbeans fine a solution for this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could try to give NetBeans the permission to access files on removable drives (however that works).

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. Apple does not let you do that manually, so I'll have to wait.

Comment: Going to Security and Privacy settings on Mac, and adding "Files and Folders" permission for these apps fixed the problem for me in my development workflow: java, Eclipse, IntelliJ and Terminal. So, I can avoid building the package each time.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on MacOS Monterey: (Thanks @Teddy)

Go to Security and Privacy settings,
-> Privacy
-> scroll down to "Files and Folders" permission
-> you may have to click the "lock" to permit changes
-> add Java
-> tick the "Downloads" box if you like

After this change, running my java app from the terminal, works.